# unity 12.04 full screen

Tags: 12.04, unity, windows, unity-2d

If I set a shortcut to 'toggle fullscreen mode' in settings->keyboard->shortcuts->windows->toggle fullscreen mode, the shortcut works in unity 2D, but not unity 3D. The same shortcut can be modified with compiz extras, and the result is the same.

Why is this, is it normal, and how to go to fullscreen mode in unity 3D ?

Answer (score 0):

To go full screen in Unity 3D just press `F11`

Perhaps setting a full screen shortcut fails because it conflicts with the existing shortcut...